# something puzzled about /proc/pid/maps & /proc/pid/pagemap files in android

Tags: android, linux, memory

Recently I get interested in /proc/pid/maps & /proc/pid/pagemap file in android and I use some tools to analyze and dump a file like this:

```
@ /proc/126/maps - /system/bin/drmserver
= becfa000-bed1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
: pfn[a676e],address[00000000A676E000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a676f],address[00000000A676F000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a676b],address[00000000A676B000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a97c1],address[00000000A97C1000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[9951b],address[000000009951B000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[9ac45],address[000000009AC45000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
```

the line starts with '@' tells some information about a process.

the line starts with '=' tells some information about virtual address for a segment in this process and here shows the stack segment.

the line starts with ':' tells the actual physical address mapped by this virtual space.And one line represents for one page.

So when I look into it, I find something puzzled.

First is that I find the the physical address range is between `0x0000000070000000 - 00000000AD9FF000`
**So is the residual space occupied by system or something else?**

Second I found that almost all the stack segments in this file have the same virtual space size, about 33 pages(33 * 4k = 132KB),and **I wonder why is that?**

Also, when I check stack segment in different processes, I find that a page or two has the same physical address, such like this:

```
= becfa000-bed1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
: pfn[a676e],address[00000000A676E000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a676f],address[00000000A676F000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a676b],address[00000000A676B000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a97c1],address[00000000A97C1000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[9951b],address[000000009951B000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[9ac45],address[000000009AC45000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]

= becfa000-bed1b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
: pfn[a676e],address[00000000A676E000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a676f],address[00000000A676F000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a5efd],address[00000000A5EFD000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a5efc],address[00000000A5EFC000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[a5eb2],address[00000000A5EB2000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[ab241],address[00000000AB241000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
: pfn[ac8b8],address[00000000AC8B8000],ispresent[1], isswapped[0]
```

And they belong to different processes, but I think the stack space should be  unique for different processes. **Do I miss something?** 
Can anyone explain it for me? Thanks a lot.